# Can anyone explain how this will work? - If else elseif in my sql

Tags: if-statement

Can somebody explain how this will work?

```
        IF (p_market_id <>0) THEN
            SET v_cont := CONCAT(v_cont,' and mrkt.location_id = ', p_market_id); 
        ELSEIF (p_region_id <>0) THEN
            SET v_cont := CONCAT(v_cont,' and reg.location_id = ', p_region_id); 
        ELSE    
            SET v_cont := CONCAT(v_cont,' and 1=1'); 
        END IF;
```

First line is clear :i.e if market_id <> 0 then the v_cont is set as given
But what i want to know is that will it go to the subsequent ELSEIF also or will it come out of the if? An what about the else?

Regards
Gautam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of an `ELSEIF` as an `ELSE IF`: it will only go there if the previous `IF` failed.  Similarly, it will only execute the final/standalone `ELSE` is all previous tests fail.